# Php Form - Error Checking and output

Tags: php, webforms

I have created a simple form which has some required fields which if not completed will pass back an error to the user to inform them that the field is require.
As there are multiple field which is checks it can output multiple error messages.

I want to know how I can define an area on my form where these errors are displayed as at the moment these error simply display at the bottom of the form, which you can't see unless you scroll down the page.

Can I define where my error are displayed.

Here is the error checking code: EDIT

```
  Old code was here
```

People in the past have suggested I make a loop to check for errors one at a time but I am novice at php so not sure how to do this.

```
    $errors = '';
    if(empty($_POST['studentName'])) 
    {
    $errors .= "You did not enter the student name<br/>";
    }

//Code to check that the Tutor Name field is completed
    if(empty($_POST['tutorName'] ))
    {
    $errors .="You did not select a tutor<br/>";
    }

//Code to check that the Procedure field is completed
    if(empty($_POST['procedure'] ))
    {
    $errors .="You did not enter a procedure<br/>";
    }
//Code to check that the Grade field is completed
    if(empty($_POST['grade'] ))
    {
    $errors .="You did not enter a grade<br/>";
    }
//Code to check that the Student Reflection field is completed
    if(empty($_POST['studentReflection'] ))
    {
    $errors .="You did not enter a reflection<br/>";
    }
//Code to check if the tick box is checked that the tutor comment is entered
    if( !strlen($_POST['tutorComments']) && isset($_POST['alert'] ))
    {
    $errors .="You must enter a reasan why you ticked the alert box";
    }

//Code to check the password field is completed and correct
    if (empty($_POST['password']))
    {
    $errors .="You did not enter you password";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['password']))
    {

//==========================================
//  ESCAPE DANGEROUS SQL CHARACTERS
//==========================================
function quote_smart($value, $handle) {

   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
       $value = stripslashes($value);
   }

   if (!is_numeric($value)) {
       $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle) . "'";
   }
   return $value;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $masterpass = $_POST['password'];
    $masterpass = htmlspecialchars($masterpass);

    //==========================================
    //  CONNECT TO THE LOCAL DATABASE
    //==========================================
    $user_name = "username";
    $pass_word = "password";
    $database = "name of database";
    $server = "server";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    if ($db_found) {

        $masterpass = quote_smart($masterpass, $db_handle);

        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM masterpass WHERE password = $masterpass";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    //====================================================
    //  CHECK TO SEE IF THE $result VARIABLE IS TRUE
    //====================================================

        if ($result) {
            if ($num_rows > 0) {
                echo "";
            }
            else {
                $errors .= "Password was not recognised";
                exit();
            }   
        }
        mysql_close($db_handle);

    }
}   
if(!empty($errors))
{
    echo '<div class="errors">' . $errors . '</div>';
    exit();
    }   

}
```

Comment: Please provide us with the entire html and php for this form and I could help. Just giving giving the section of php that does the error checking does not provide all the information needed to answer this question.

Comment: You will find it easier to develop and debug your code if you use proper indentation.

Comment: I would suggest using some form of javascript for frontend error checking directly to the user. This can get very messy with just using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo()ing your errors is what's adding them to the bottom.  As the previous answer suggested, assigning them to a string and printing that in a defined div (if it's not empty) is how the pros do it!

Defining errors as an array also works, and allows you a bit more fine-grained control over the error process.

```
$errors = array();
if(empty($_POST['studentName'])) 
    $errors[] = "You did not enter the student name";

if(empty($_POST['tutorName'] ))
    $errors[] = "You did not select a tutor name.";

//etc...

//At the top of your page.
if (sizeof($errors)>0) {
    echo "<div class='errordiv'>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($errors as $err) {
        echo "<li>".$err."</li>"; //or whatever format you want!
    }
    echo "</ul></div>";
}
```

You can also pass the error array around as a parameter to other functions, log them, etc.

Comment: You added the following at the end of your error check block:
`if (!empty($_POST['password'])) {`
This is causing your "error check if password filled" problem.  The rest of your code is executing inside that block.  Remove those.  Also, if you exit() immediately after printing the error div, execution stops there.  You still want to display your form, I'm guessing!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
$errors = '';

if(empty($_POST['studentName'])) 
{
  $errors .= "You did not enter the student name<br />";
}

if(empty($_POST['tutorName'] ))
{
  $errors .= "You did not select a tutor name.<br />";
}

// etc.
```

and then above your `<form>` have

```
if (!empty($errors))
{
  echo '<div class="errors">' . $errors . '</div>';
}
```

styling `.errors` with CSS so it'll stand out more. If `$errors` is blank higher up in your application logic, you can then perform the usual add / update to a database and redirect to a *success* page.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that but forgot to add that I have another field for password that gets checked. I have updated this but now the error checking only occurs if the user enters a password, if they leave this blank it just submits the data to the database without checking. Will update my code above to show you what I have now

Comment: Move your validation checks to below your form check after submission, i.e. after `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){` (also see @soylentplaid's comment).

Comment: thanks guys. I have managed to work it out with the help of these posts